# How can I store a number of sprites in a 2D array?

Tags: c++, arrays, sprite

I'm writing code for a simple 2D game and I'm having troubling acccessing and displaying sprites. The sprites are simple 2D arrays like this:

```
static int nl[8][8] =  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  
                       0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  
                       0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,  
                       1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,  
                       1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,  
                       0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,  
                       0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,  
                       0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0 };
```

With 1's for pixel on, 0's for pixel off (The game is for a 84x48 lcd screen).
I have 12 of these sprites and need to save them in another 2d array like this:

```
double tank_sprites[4][3] =  {nl,el,sl,wl,  
                              nf,ef,sf,wf,  
                              nr,er,sr,wr};
```

The sprites will be called later from this array. I am getting lots of errors and such, is this the wrong way to go about this?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: You should be more accurate about the errors you're facing for us to be able to help you more.

Comment: `tank_sprites[4][3]` or `tank_sprites[3][4]` ?

Comment: "Lots of errors" is unhelpful.

Comment: Please see this on [how to ask a  good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to store pointers in an array of floating-point numbers; `int[8][8]`decays into `int(*)[8]`, a pointer to an array of eight `int`s.
That can't possibly work.

You need to use the correct types.
I recommend a type alias because figuring out how to declare "an array of arrays of pointers to arrays" is no fun.

```
using sprite = int(*)[8];
sprite tank_sprites[4][3] =  {nl,el,sl,wl,  
                              nf,ef,sf,wf,  
                              nr,er,sr,wr};
```

Note that `tank_sprites` is

```
{{nl,el,sl},
 {wl,nf,ef},
 {sf,wf,nr},
 {er,sr,wr}}
```

which I would guess, based on your linebreaks and the naming, possibly isn't what you expect.
Use brackets to make your intent clear and give the compiler a chance to catch as many issues as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
double tank_sprites[4][3] =  {nl,el,sl,wl,  
                              nf,ef,sf,wf,  
                              nr,er,sr,wr};
```

Says it is an array of doubles, but you are not putting doubles into it. You are trying to put in elements of type `array of static int[8][8]`

You need to create a class that represents your Sprite.

```
class Sprite
{
    int * m_data;

    // Some Interface 
};
```

Internally store the data for the sprite how you like. Then create a collection of Sprites:

```
std::vector<Sprite> sprites;
```